# How to solve this problem related to C++ 20 Module?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c++20

I encountered a problem when trying to use the new features of C++(module), the code is as follows:

```
//Module.ixx
export module Module;

import <string>;
import <iterator>;
import <sstream>;
import <iomanip>;
import <cstdint>;

template<typename T>
class blake_mixin
{
public:

};

template<typename T, size_t N>
struct stream_width_fixer
{
    stream_width_fixer(T value) : v(value) {}
    T v;
};

template<typename T, size_t N>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const stream_width_fixer<T, N>& value)
{
    return ostr << std::setw(N) << value.v;
}

template<typename T>
struct null_mixin
{
    //for example
    void sample()
    {
        std::ostringstream someone;
    }
};

class blake_provider
{
public:
    static const bool is_xof = false;

    blake_provider(size_t hashsize)
    {
        
    }

    ~blake_provider()
    {
        
    }
};

template<class HashProvider, template <class> class Mixin = null_mixin>
class hasher : public Mixin<HashProvider>
{
public:

    template<typename H = HashProvider>
    hasher(size_t hashsize) : provider(hashsize)
    {

    }
    template<typename H = HashProvider>
    inline std::string hexdigest() const
    {
        std::ostringstream res;
        res << std::setfill('0') << std::hex;
        return res.str();
    }


private:
    friend Mixin<HashProvider>;
    HashProvider provider;
};

export typedef hasher<blake_provider, blake_mixin> blake;
//main.cpp
import Module;
int main()
{
    blake(256).hexdigest();
}
```

Please forgive the clutter of the code, the code has no practical meaning and is only used to demonstrate the problem. Because I want to ask questions more concisely, I have simplified a lot of details, but the problem is very clear. I only need to add this line of code to any class and it will be successfully compiled,

```
    void sample()
    {
        std::ostringstream someone;
    }
```

but I think the behavior is meaningless and I am stuck Confused, please tell me where I am wrong. Many thanks
When this code is not added, an error message will pop up

```
(68,28): error C2079: 'res' uses undefined class 'std::basic_ostringstream<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
```

The development tool I use is VS2019, and I have also tried it on VS2020, and they will encounter the same problem.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. The error occours in hexdigest. What is the meaning of "I only need to add this line of code to any class and it will be successfully compiled..." Can you clarify: what do you add to what to resolve the error?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have revised the question to make it easier to understand. I am still troubled by this question until now. I look forward to your answer.